# Workflow Call HTTP Web Service returns xml instead of Json

Tags: office-365, designer-workflow, rest

I developed a Workflow that uses *http call webservice* in our devlopment site on O365.   When I rebuilt the identical workflow in production, it fails with the error:

> System.IO.InvalidDataException: Unable to deserialize HTTP response
>   content. Expected ContentType : 'application/json', 'text/plain' or
>   'text/html', Received ContentType : 'application/atom+xml'

This indicates to me that the headers that specify Json response are not getting to SharePoint.

I am setting the request headers in both calls the same - and the log shows the values are the same in both: `{"Accept":"application\/json;odata=verbose","Content-Type":"application\/json;odata=verbose"}`

What could be different in the two environments - and what would I have to change to make it work in production?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A co-worker ran across this issue, and I found the resolution to it on another site. It boils down to this:

"To resolve this issue we need to pass `Accept` and `Content-Type` as `application/json;odata=verbose` to both the **response headers** and **request headers**. This way we will get JSON response."

For a full explanation and walk-through, please see Prasad Pathak's Technology Blog post on this from Feb 2015. [SharePoint 2013: Desinger workflow error with 'Call HTTP web service' action](https://prasadpathak.wordpress.com/tag/unable-to-deserialize-http-response-content/).

Comment: Great answer with great link to solution. It solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the accepted answer fix does not work -

I too had ran into this issue. In my code, I verified the point mentioned in the accepted answer but that was not the mistake which I had made.

So on further investigation, I realized that there were some look-up columns used in the list which was being queried using REST api. The correction required for was that a **select** condition was needed to be added in the REST url for making the fix.